# Anchor clockwork-sdk error

Tags: anchor

I have a basic anchor project with no modifications made other then adding the clockwork-sdk in Cargo.toml. When I run anchor build without the clockwork-sdk the program builds. When I run it with the clockwork-sdk I get the error in the screenshot (unfortunately the console output was a little to much to fully screenshot it so I just screenshotted the beginning and the end of the output, but maybe this is enough for someone to tell me at least what my problem could be). As I said in the beginning it's just an basic anchor project (using anchor 0.28.0) freshly inited without any modification other than adding the latest version of clockwork (v. 2.0.18). I've spend the last few days searching the Internet but couldn't find anything. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: first part of the console output]

[image: second part of the console output]

Comment: can you share your contract here? so able to identify things.

Comment: @IshaPadalia the contract is just the rust file you get when you init an anchor project I didn't change anything there the only thing I did was adding the dependency for the clockwork-sdk to Cargo.toml

Comment: Appears maybe your version of `spl-token-2022` (or the version in `anchor-spl`) is not compatible with the version used by the Clockwork SDK. Maybe there's a version of clockwork where you can align versions for `spl-token-2022`?

Comment: @JoeC the only dependencies I have in Cargo.toml are anchor-lang and clockwork-sdk I don't use anchor-spl in this project

Comment: I solved the problem I found the solution on the clockwork Discord

Comment: I just updated the Anchor deps to v0.29.0 today. Let me know if you run into any issues using that.